# Heatmap plot of array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array composed of the following arrays (as example):

my_array = [[10,12,0],[10,13,1],[11,12,1],[11,13,0],[12,12,1],[12,13,0]]

Where items are [x,y,value]

I want to plot a heatmap or similar with x values in X, y values i Y, and color depending on value (0 or 1). I want also label color for 0 as 'A points' and color for 1 as 'B points'.

I have tried several heatmaps but can't imagine how to solve this three value aray to be plotted.

Code tried:

```
xvals = [10,11,12]
yvals = [12,13]

zvals = [[10,12,0],[10,13,1],[11,12,1],[11,13,0],[12,12,1],[12,13,0]]


heatmap, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.imshow(zvals,cmap='inferno',extent=[xvals[0],xvals[2],yvals[0],yvals[1]],interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
ax.set(xlabel='some x', ylabel='some y')

cbar = heatmap.colorbar(im)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('stuff')

heatmap.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Your code does not run. There are no imports, xvals is not defined.
In addition, what do you expect that is wrong with he current output of your code ?

Comment: Yes, import was missing but it's a standar one (I edited the question). The heatmap divides x and y in decimals, and I want no division. The colored box is not centered to the x or y value. And the color doesn''t match. I have only 0 and 1, not that color dispersion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a 2d list or numpy 2d array and plt that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xvals = [10,11,12]
yvals = [12,13]
zvals = [[10,12,0],[10,13,1],[11,12,1],[11,13,0],[12,12,1],[12,13,0]]

im = [[0 for j in range(len(xvals))] for i in range(len(yvals))]

for val in zvals:
    im[val[1] - yvals[0]][val[0] - xvals[0]] = val[-1]

plt.imshow(im, cmap='inferno')
plt.xticks(range(len(xvals)), xvals)
plt.yticks(range(len(yvals)), yvals)
```

and results:

[image]

Comment: @QuimQuadrada Glad that it helped, generally it it is bigger size of data go with numpy arrays